# nutch crawl path

Tags: nutch

I would like to know how to make nutch crawl not only the domain that I specified, but also the dir path within the domain that I specified.  I know that you can configure this information on regex-urlfilter.txt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should crawl only the domain/path you want :

```
+.*www\.domain\.com/yourpath/.*  
#skip everything else  
-.*
```